# How to create a Filter without locking the browser?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

First I start this topic warning that unfortunately I can not make requests for this method. It works as follows:

When the user accesses the page, a request is made and saved in session storage, from the session storage that I should search with the filter.

After the search in the session storage is completed with the words that refer to those characters entered, I render in the HTML all the words found.

I'm using some ES6 methods, but when I add some unintentional characters like for example:

1) Miscellaneous "..."
2) Various blanks

The layout (Browser) it starts to crash, but if I do not make mistakes I can bring me all the query I want ..

How should this component work? The user will enter some characters in the input and above a character the search for this "word" begins ..

The search is done in the session estorage where it contains more than 4k of data.

```
abstract class FilterController {
    protected readonly _storageKey: string;
    protected readonly _typingValue: HTMLInputElement;
    protected readonly _bodyContainer: HTMLElement;
    protected readonly _listboxMain: HTMLElement;
    protected readonly _listboxSecondary: HTMLElement;

    constructor(storageKey: string, typingValue: HTMLInputElement, bodyContainer: HTMLElement, listboxMain: HTMLElement, listboxSecondary: HTMLElement){
        this._storageKey = storageKey;
        this._typingValue = typingValue;
        this._bodyContainer = bodyContainer;
        this._listboxMain = listboxMain;
        this._listboxSecondary = listboxSecondary;
    }

    protected get typedValue(): any {
        return this._typingValue.value;
    }

    protected get storageData(): any {
        return this.convertToJSON(sessionStorage.getItem(this._storageKey));
    }

    protected convertToJSON(_data: any): JSON {
        if (_data) {
            return JSON.parse(_data);
        }
    }

    protected blockFirstWhiteSpace(_event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (this.typedValue.length === 0 && _event.code == 'Space') {
            _event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    protected blockFirstPoint(_event: KeyboardEvent): void {
        if (this.typedValue.length === 1 && _event.code == 'Period') {
            _event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

}

export default class FilterData extends FilterController {
    private _dataFound: any;

    constructor(storageKey: string, typingValue: HTMLInputElement, containerMain: HTMLElement, listboxMain: HTMLElement, listboxSecondary: HTMLElement) {
        super(storageKey, typingValue, containerMain, listboxMain, listboxSecondary);
    }

    private set dataFound(_data: any) {
        this._dataFound = _data;
    }

    private get dataFound(): any {
        return this._dataFound;
    }

    public initComponent() :void {
        this._typingValue.addEventListener('keypress', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            this.blockFirstWhiteSpace(_event);
            this.blockFirstPoint(_event);
        });

        this._typingValue.addEventListener('keyup', (_event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            if (this.typedValue.length >= 2) {
                this.search();
            }
        });
    }

    private search(): void {
        if (this.storageData) {
            if (this.typedValue.length === 2) {
                this.filterDataIndex();
            } else if (this.typedValue.length > 2) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.filterData();
                }, 50);
            }
        }
    }

    private filterData(): void {
        this.dataFound = this.storageData.filter((_value: any) => {
            let storageItemIndex = _value.search(this.typedValue.toUpperCase());
            if (storageItemIndex !== -1) {
                return this.storageData[storageItemIndex];
            }
        });
    }

    private filterDataIndex(): void {
        let storageItemIndex = this.storageData.indexOf(this.typedValue.toUpperCase());
        if (storageItemIndex !== -1) {
            this.dataFound = this.storageData[storageItemIndex];
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Javascript has no public/private/protected, can you please make sure to use the right tags?

Comment: Javascript does not, however I'm using Typescript! That nothing else is a superset of javascript and which compiled turns a JS too ..

The only visual difference you will see is object orientation, the rest is identical.

Comment: yes but there's a reason there are tags on SO, so if you tag a typescript question with javascript, several thousand people subscribed to that tag, getting notifcation emails etc. will go ".. what?". So be nice to those people please. Remember: many of them don't know, or even care about, typescript, whereas everyone subscribed to the typescript tag does.